# This is mysql code where I'm getting the following error while initializing this variable please help me solving

Tags: sql

This is the sql code:

```
create database task1
use task1
create table t1
( Finishedproduct VARCHAR(200),
  Rawmaterials VARCHAR(200),
  Weigh FLOAT,
  Cost FLOAT,
  Labcost FLOAT,
  Electcost FLOAT,
  Miscost FLOAT
);
Declare @var char
SET @var = 'Pizza' ;
select distinct Rawmaterials  from t1 where Finishedproduct=@var
```

> Error is: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Must declare the scalar
> variable "@var".

I'm struck with this error. Can anyone help me with solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your version is older, but don't declare the variable first, just set it using my syntax and see if it works. I am using MySQL 8.0, here is code.

```
create table t1
( Finishedproduct VARCHAR(200),
  Rawmaterials VARCHAR(200),
  Weigh FLOAT,
  Cost FLOAT,
  Labcost FLOAT,
  Electcost FLOAT,
  Miscost FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO t1(Finishedproduct,Rawmaterials,Weigh,Cost,Labcost,Electcost,Miscost)
VALUES ('Pizza','Tomato,Cheese,Onion,Chicken',0.62,10.50,1,1,1);

SET @var := 'Pizza';
select distinct Rawmaterials from t1 where Finishedproduct = @var;
```

My output is this,

```
Rawmaterials
Tomato,Cheese,Onion,Chicken
```

Look at the documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

However, I believe if you are using mysql 5, you have to declare the variable first. You also have to declare the size.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html

You can try

```
create table t1
( Finishedproduct VARCHAR(200),
  Rawmaterials VARCHAR(200),
  Weigh FLOAT,
  Cost FLOAT,
  Labcost FLOAT,
  Electcost FLOAT,
  Miscost FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO t1(Finishedproduct,Rawmaterials,Weigh,Cost,Labcost,Electcost,Miscost)
VALUES ('Pizza','Tomato,Cheese,Onion,Chicken',0.62,10.50,1,1,1);

DECLARE @var varchar(10);
SET @var = 'Pizza';
select distinct Rawmaterials from t1 where Finishedproduct = @var;
```

Comment: It didn't worked if declaration part is removed it will ask to declare the variable.

Comment: @AbhishekDixit it works fine for me, what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @AbhishekDixit look at my answer again, i updated it with an example and it works.

Comment: @AbhishekDixit please mark my answer correct if it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the length of the variable.you want to declare

`Declare @var char(30)`